# Pass variable from form to php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Did my best to not post this question but i just can not figure this one out. I'm trying to pass a variable from my html form to a php script the code looks like this so far

```
<?PHP
echo "<b>Previously Submitted</b><br />";
echo "<select name='files' onChange='updateInfo();'>";
echo "<option value=''></option>";
$files = scandir("businesses");
foreach ($files as $file)
    if($file != "."){
      if($file != ".."){
        if($file != "form.php"){
          echo "<option value='$file'>". htmlspecialchars($file) ."</option>";
        }
      }
    }
echo "</select>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInfo(){
  <?PHP
    mysql_connect("HOSTHERE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    mysql_select_db("USERNAME");
    //This is the line that is of interest i can't figure how to pass document.forms['frm'].files.value to my query
    $bizname = mysql_query("SELECT `Value` FROM `" . document.forms['frm'].files.value . "` WHERE `Variable` LIKE 'Name'");
    $bizValue = mysql_fetch_assoc($bizname);
    echo "document.forms['frm'].businessname.value = '" . $bizValue['Value'] . "';";
    mysql_close();
  ?>
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how i can pass a value from my drop down to the php code.

**EDIT**

Just to clear things up on what i'm doing sorry about some confusion basically i have a dropdown menu and when the dropdown menu is changed i want to query my database using whatever is in the dropdown as the table in the query and then what ever the value i get from the database is set in my form in a text field. It's all in one page and just trying to update the text filed when the dropdown is changed

Comment: You can't combine php and javascript like that, the PHP is only interpreted on page load. If you want to update without a page refresh, look into ajax.

Comment: have you solved your problem or not? what error you are getting?

Comment: I haven't it's not working still and have been trying to tweak what your answer was i added <?PHP ?> arround both the first set of code you provided and the third (the ajaxrequest.php) i added in my database login credentials to ajaxrequest.php as well. Lastly i set url: './ajaxrequest.php' since the file is in the same directory as my html file

Comment: i have given you a link to download a code. check my updated ansewer. go to file menu and download zip file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have written updateInfo script is not possible. using php concatenation (i.e ".") you can concatenate only php variables not java-script. PHP does not understand it.

what i suggest you is to use ajax. In your updateInfo pass the changed value.

```
<?php
echo "<select name='files' onChange='updateInfo(this.value);'>";
echo "<option value=''></option>";
$files = scandir("business");
foreach ($files as $file)
    if($file != "."){
      if($file != ".."){
        if($file != "form.php"){
          echo "<option value='$file'>". htmlspecialchars($file) ."</option>";
        }
      }
    }
echo "</select>";
?>
```

and then send ajax and get response. and treat response as you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInfo(val){
$.ajax({
   url: '/path/to/ajaxrequest.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {'file':val}
   success: function(response){
      document.forms['frm'].businessname.value = response;
   }
});
</script>
```

and your ajaxrequest.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])=='xmlhttprequest'){

mysql_connect("HOSTHERE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("USERNAME");

$file = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['file']);

$bizname = mysql_query("SELECT `Value` FROM ".$file." WHERE `Variable` LIKE 'Name'");
$bizValue = mysql_fetch_assoc($bizname);
$assignVal = $bizValue['Value']; 
mysql_close();

echo $assignVal;
}
?>
```

if you don't get this let me know. thank you.

here i am giving you a link to [download code](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_MdP7QR7kseYlVQUVI3ajBveG8)

Comment: Thank you so much was able to get it working had to change up the query to work how i needed it but you went above and beyond with the link and sample code up vote and check :)

Comment: Set it up to send back an array from a query and change a lot of text inputs even was able to echo back some php to show all images in each folder which is listed in the dropdown was able to learn a ton from your code much appreciated been able to add a lot i didn't think i'd be able to do

Answer (score 0):

Put  tag inside the HTML Form element..Also I have not understood why you are merging  javascript and PHP mysql update function. 
yo can write code like
1.Form Element with

Done.

Answer (score 0):

you need to submit the form. you can use post or get as method. but without submitting you can not pass variable from html to php.

```
<?PHP
echo "<form name='frm_1' id='frm_1' action='your_destination_page.php' method='post>'";
echo "<b>Previously Submitted</b><br />";
echo "<select name='files' onChange='updateInfo();'>";
echo "<option value=''></option>";
$files = scandir("businesses");
foreach ($files as $file)
    if($file != "."){
      if($file != ".."){
        if($file != "form.php"){
          echo "<option value='$file'>". htmlspecialchars($file) ."</option>";
        }
      }
    }
echo "</select></form>";
```

?>

on destination page write this on the top of the page

```
<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";?>
```

you will have values of all controls in $_POST array.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?PHP
echo "<b>Previously Submitted</b><br />";
echo "<select name='files' onChange='updateInfo();'>";
echo "<option value=''></option>";
$files = scandir("businesses");
foreach ($files as $file)
    if($file != "."){
      if($file != ".."){
        if($file != "form.php"){
          echo "<option value='$file'>". htmlspecialchars($file) ."</option>";
        }
      }
    }
echo "</select>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInfo(){
  <?PHP
    mysql_connect("HOSTHERE","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    mysql_select_db("USERNAME");
    //This is the line that is of interest i can't figure how to pass document.forms['frm'].files.value to my query
    $bizname = mysql_query("SELECT `Value` FROM `" . document.forms['frm'].files.value . "` WHERE `Variable` LIKE 'Name'");
    $bizValue = mysql_fetch_assoc($bizname);
    $assignVal = $bizValue['Value'];
    echo "<script>document.forms['frm'].businessname.value = '" .$assignVal . "';</script>";
    mysql_close();


     ?>
}
```

Try enclosing in a script tag.